# Matlab struct type looses type of cell array field?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'd like to use a struct() to return various values in a Matlab function.  One of those is a cell array.  Here's an example:

```
xnames = cell( 3, 1 ) ;
for i = [1:3]
   xnames{i} = sprintf( 'V_%d', i ) ;
end

a = 1 ;
b = 2 ;
r = struct( 'a', a, 'b', b, 'x', xnames ) ;
```

However, if I attempt to access r.x, it appears that the original cell-identity is lost:

```
x = r.x ;
x{1}
```

This results in the error: 'Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.'  The string data appears to be there, as a display of r.x shows:

```
ans =

V_1


ans =

V_2


ans =

V_3
```

However, I don't know how to get at these fields after inserting the cell array into the struct?

EDIT: using the gui variable explorer for the above example, shows that r ends up with the results:

```
1   2   'V_1'
1   2   'V_2'
1   2   'V_3'
```

i.e. it got converted into an array of struct(), one for each of the values of xnames{i}:

```
>> r(1)

ans =

    a: 1
    b: 2
    x: 'V_1'

>> r(2)

ans =

    a: 1
    b: 2
    x: 'V_2'

>> r(3)

ans =

    a: 1
    b: 2
    x: 'V_3'
```

So, the problem isn't how to access this field x as a cell-array, but how to keep it a cell array on insertion into the struct() initializer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose `xnames` in braces to keep it as a cell array:

```
r = struct( 'a', a, 'b', b, 'x', {xnames} ) ;
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html#inputarg_value), the way the `struct` function handles cell arrays the way you call it means you would access `V1`, `V2`, `V3` using

```
r(1).x
r(2).x
r(3).x
```

You can get the behaviour you want either by following David's suggestion or by using.

```
r.x = xnames;
```